# Draw Histogram of depth image?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, kinect, openni

i am working with depth image from kinect. i want to calculate histogram of depth image, a/f:

```
     Mat depth; //(take from kinect sdk)

   int histSize = 64;

 // Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )

  float range[] = { 0, 256 } ;

   const float* histRange = { range };

    bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;

    Mat depth_hist;

   // Compute the histograms:

  calcHist( &depth, 1, 0, Mat(), depth_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );

 // Draw the histograms for depth

   int hist_w = 320; int hist_h = 240;

   int bin_w = cvRound( (double) hist_w/histSize );

   Mat histImage( hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC1, 1 );

   // Normalize the result to [ 0, histImage.rows ]

    normalize(depth_hist, depth_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

     // Draw for each channel
  for( int i = 1; i < histSize; i++ )
          {
  line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(depth_hist.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                   Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(depth_hist.at<float>(i)) ),
                   Scalar( 255), 2, 8, 0  );
  }

 // Display
 namedWindow("calcHist Demo", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 imshow("calcHist Demo", histImage );
```

But, It is not working :(. I take this code for an **Grayscale Image**, it works fine. I don't know

what is error?

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly is not working. What do you get and what do you expect to get. Also, please post any code relevant to how you obtain the depth image and any if there is any processing done on it.

Answer (score 0):

Depth has a range bigger than 0-256 (You should assume 0-10000), Maybe this is the reason for the failure...